# python subprocess hide stdout and wait it to complete

Tags: python, synchronization, subprocess, stdout

I have this code:

```
def method_a(self):
    command_line = 'somtoolbox GrowingSOM ' + som_prop_path
    subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command_line))
    ......

def method_b(self): .....
....
```

and like you all see, method_a has a subprocess that is calling the somtoolbox program. But this program have a long stdout, and I want to hide it. I tried:

```
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command_line), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But it returned this sentence:

```
cat: record error: Broked Pipe
```

(this is a translation of the portuguese sentence: "cat: erro de gravação: Pipe quebrado")
(I'm from brazil)

Also, I have other methods (like method_b there), that are called after the method_a, and tis methods are running before the subprocess complete the process.

How I can hide the stdout at all (and don't want it anywhere), and make the other code wait for the subprocess to finish the execution ?

Obs: The somtoolbox is a java program, that gives the long output to the terminal. 
Tried:

```
outputTuple = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command_line), stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

but continuous returning output to the shell.
Help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way to do that is to redirect the output into /dev/null.  You can do that like this:

```
devnull = open('/dev/null', 'w')
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command_line), stdout=devnull)
```

Then to wait until it's done, you can use .wait() on the Popen object, getting you to this:

```
devnull = open('/dev/null', 'w')
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command_line), stdout=devnull)
retcode = process.wait()
```

retcode will then contain the return code of the process.

ADDITIONAL:  As mentioned in comments, this won't hide stderr.  To hide stderr as well you'd do it like so:

```
devnull = open('/dev/null', 'w')
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command_line), stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
retcode = process.wait()
```

Comment: @Gabriel Maybe you need to redirect stderr too?

Comment: It works on Windows too if you replace '/dev/null' with os.devnull (which exists since 2.4, like subprocess itself)

Comment: Note that you can use `subprocess.DEVNULL` in Python 3.3+ instead of `open('/dev/null', 'w')`.

Answer (score 5):

[`Popen.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) is used to wait for the process to terminate. For example:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
outputTuple = Popen(["gcc", "--version"], stdout = PIPE).communicate()
```

will return a tuple of strings, one for stdout and another one for stderr output.

Comment: It didn't work. See my last phrase, to see if it changes something. Its an output of a java program...see there, please.