# SIFT implementation Python error

Tags: python, sift

I am using the SIFT implementation from vlfeat.org in Python, vlfeat.py.

I keep getting an error stating **too many indices** and the line number indicates that the error occurs when `read_features_from_file()` is executed.

I also noticed that the file *features1.sift* is empty, meaning something goes wrong when `executing process_image()`.

**Code Snippet** :

```
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *
import vlfeat as vlf

vlf.process_image('semper1.jpg','features1.sift', params="--edge-thresh 10 --peak-thresh 5")
l1,d1 = vlf.read_features_from_file('features1.sift')
image = array(Image.open('semper1.jpg'))

vlf.process_image('semper2.jpg','features2.sift', params="--edge-thresh 10 --peak-thresh 5")
l2,d2 = vlf.read_features_from_file('feautures2.sift')
image2 = array(Image.open('semper2.jpg'))   

matches = vlf.match(d1,d2)

imshow(image)

for k in xrange(len(matches)):
    if matches[k] > 0:
        plot(l1[k, 0], l1[k, 1], 'r.')
        plot([l1[k,0], l2[matches[k,0],0]], [l1[k,1], l2[matches[k,0],1]], 'b-')

show()
```

Here's what process_image looks like:

```
def process_image(imagename,resultname,params="--edge-thresh 10 --peak-thresh 5"): 
""" process an image and save the results in a file""" 
if imagename[-3:] != 'pgm': 
    #create a pgm file 
    im = Image.open(imagename).convert('L') 
    im.save('tmp.pgm') 
    imagename = 'tmp.pgm' 
    cmmd = str("sift "+imagename+" --output="+resultname+ " "+params) 
    os.system(cmmd) 
    print 'processed', imagename, 'to', resultname
```

Comment: Is process_image possibly occur in async?

Comment: This is what process_image() look like:def process_image(imagename,resultname,params="--edge-thresh 10 --peak-thresh 5"):
 """ process an image and save the results in a file"""

 if imagename[-3:] != 'pgm':
  #create a pgm file
  im = Image.open(imagename).convert('L')
  im.save('tmp.pgm')
  imagename = 'tmp.pgm'

 cmmd = str("sift "+imagename+" --output="+resultname+
    " "+params)
 os.system(cmmd)
 print 'processed', imagename, 'to', resultname

Comment: It'd be better to add it to the original post, where you can format it to code.

Comment: Don't know how to display that correctly.

Comment: I've added it myself. Looks like it is async as it calls an external program via cmd called sift.exe. Does this python vlf module have a handler/callback for when its finished processing?

Comment: I am not sure if it has.

Comment: Are you sure you can use process_image() with .jpg files? Have you tried with converting to .pgm first?

Comment: This is the link to the vlfeat.py: [link](http://www.janeriksolem.net/2011/06/another-python-interface-for-sift.html)

Comment: I'd try MatteoD's idea then.

Comment: Also does not work with .pgm.

Answer (score 1):

Try the older vlfeat version i used the binary vlfeat-0.9.21-bin.tar.gz  which gave me that error. Try using the older version vlfeat-0.9.20-bin.tar.gz.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is async as it calls an external program via cmd called sift.exe.

```
cmmd = str("sift "+imagename+" --output="+resultname+ " "+params) 
os.system(cmmd)
```

Does this python vlf module have a handler/callback for when its finished processing?

Otherwise, if you can modify the process_image function, you can use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and wait till the external application finishes before returning to process. 
Also see [python subprocess hide stdout and wait it to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125525/python-subprocess-hide-stdout-and-wait-it-to-complete)

Edit:

Make sure you have the external sift.exe accessible from the python working directory.

Answer (score 0):

SIFT is now available as part of main opencv repository (patent on SIFT is expired).

you can check it with the latest version of opencv (as of today 4.4). Try sift using the below code.

```
cv2.SIFT_create()
```